# Scala lower bound does not behave as I expect

Tags: scala, lower-bound, upperbound

Today I spent a few hours to understand the logic behind Lower Bounds in Scala but the more I read the more confusing it gets. Would you please shed some light on this?

Here is the simple class hierarchy for our workshop:

```java
class Animal
class Pet extends Animal
class Wild extends Animal

class Dog extends Pet
class Cat extends Pet

class Lion extends Wild
class Tiger extends Wild
```

So the hierarchy would be something like:

```java
        Animal
        /    \
      Pet    Wild
      / \    /  \
    Dog Cat Lion Tiger
```

And here is the client code:

```java
 object Main extends App {
  //I expect the compilation of passing any type above Pet to fail
  def upperBound[T <: Pet](t: T) = {println(t.getClass.getName)}

  //I expect the compilation of passing any type below Pet to fail
  def lowerBound[T >: Pet](t: T) = {println(t.getClass.getName)}

  upperBound(new Dog)//Ok, As expected
  upperBound(new Cat)//Ok, As expected
  upperBound(new Pet)//Ok, As expected
  //Won't compile (as expected) because Animal is not a sub-type of Pet
  upperBound(new Animal)

  lowerBound(new Pet)//Ok, As expected
  lowerBound(new Animal)//Ok, As expected
  //I expected this to fail because Dog is not a super type of Pet
  lowerBound(new Dog)
  //I expected this to fail because Lion is not a super type of Pet either
  lowerBound(new Lion)
  lowerBound(100)//Jesus! What's happening here?!
  lowerBound(Nil)// Ok! I am out!!! :O
}
```

Well... The last four lines of the code does not make any sense to me! From what I understand, Lower Bound does not impose any constraints on the type parameter at all. Is there an implicit Bound to `Any` or `AnyRef` somewhere which I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain the unexpected behaviour of bounded type inference

1. Upper Bound(T <: Pet): This means T is applicable for all the classes which has inherited at least the Pet class or any of Pet's subclasses.
2. Lower Bound(T >: Pet): This means T is applicable for all the classes which has inherited **at least one of the parent class of Pet class**.

So as you correctly guessed, **AnyRef is a super type of all object/reference types**. So when we say

```
lowerBound(new Dog())
```

Dog is under the class AnyRef. So by lower bound, since AnyRef is a parent of Pet, the compiler throws no warning.

You can see similar behaviour for the **::** method of scala List class. With List you can do the following without any compile errors.

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3)

val newList = "Hello" :: list
```

For further reading, please take a look at these stack overflow answers:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19217523/4046067
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19821995/4046067

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer tawkir. Tbh that's not what I expected at all. In that case, would that be a correct statement to say that `[T >: 'Any Arbitrary Type']` is always logically identical to `[T <: Any]`? If that's true, lower bound doesn't seem to be a constraint at all and it could be written in something like `[Any]` or `[ _ ]` (in theory)!

Comment: @AlexGolshani No, they are not at all equivalent: the compiler will infer different `T`s for these constraints. E.g. in `lowerBound(new Dog)` with `T >: Pet` it infers `Animal`, with `T <: Any` it infers `Dog`. It matters when `T` is a part of the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see why some of these work. You can inspect the typed inferred by scalac by using the `-Xprint:typer` flag. This is what we see:

```
NewTest.this.lowerBound[tests.NewTest.Pet](new NewTest.this.Dog());
NewTest.this.lowerBound[tests.NewTest.Animal](new NewTest.this.Lion());
NewTest.this.lowerBound[Any](100)
```

For the case of `Dog`, the compiler looks for an ancestor that will match the lower bound requirement, which `Pet` satisfies since `Pet >: Pet`. For `Lion`, the ancestor matching the requirement is `Animal`, which works since `Animal >: Pet`. For the last one, the compiler infers `Any`, which is the highest in the Scala type hierarchy, which also works because `Any >: Pet`.

All of these work since the definition of a lower bound is that any type which is higher up the type hierarchy may be a candidate. This is why, if we take the most contrived example, passing an `Int` works, since the only common ancestor of `Int` and `Pet` is `Any`.

Comment: Appreciate the answer @Yuval. Thanks mate. Referring to your comment, "This is why, if we take the most contrived example, passing an Int works, since the only common ancestor of Int and Pet is Any", since everything inherits from `Any` it means as soon as you put a lower bound constraint there (with any lower type), any Scala type will satisfy the condition, did I get it right? I just put `[T >: Any]`, `[T >: Int]` and `[T >: Null]` on `lowerBound` function and I got the same behaviour every time!

Comment: @AlexGolshani When you put a lower bound you say "I want a type no lower than `Pet`, meaning nothing more specific. You are not saying anything regarding the upper bound of this `T`, so yes, `Any` will work here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your expected results by changing the definition to

```
def lowerBound[T](t: T)(implicit ev: Pet <:< T) = ...
```

This tells the compiler to infer `T` (so it will be `Lion`, `Int`, and `Nil.type` in the last three cases) and *then* check if `Pet` is a subtype of `T`, instead of inferring `T` *such that* `Pet` is a subtype.